# Суммы элементов массива: а) до последнего положительного элемента; б) на пересечении строки/столбца с Max значением

Tags: excel, vba

Нужно создать матрицу из случайных значений, определить две суммы.

Матрицу создал. Нашел сумму элементов столбца и строки матрицы, на пересечении которых находится максимальный элемент матрицы.

Пытался найти сумму элементов массива, расположенных до последнего правого нижнего положительного элемента. Не получилось. В чем ошибка?

```
Private Sub cmdb2_Click()

Dim M As Long, N As Long
 Dim i As Long, j As Long
 Dim sum As Long, sum1 As Long, sum2 As Long, sump As Long

 Cells.Clear
    M = txt1.Value
    N = txt2.Value
Dim B() As Double
ReDim B(1 To M, 1 To N)
For i = 1 To M
  For j = 1 To N
   Cells(i, j) = Int((-10 - 10 + 1) * Rnd + 10)
  Next j
Next i
 sum2 = 0: sum = 0: sum1 = 0:
Max = Cells(1, 1)
For i = 1 To M
  For j = 1 To N
   If Cells(i, j) >= Max Then
      Max = Cells(i, j): jMax = j: iMax = i
      End If
    Next
Next i

Cells(N + 2, 5) = Max
Cells(N + 2, 1) = " Максимальный элемент: Max = "

  sum = 0: sumj = 0: sumi = 0
  For i = 1 To M
  sumi = sumi + Cells(i, jMax)
  Next
  For j = 1 To N
  sumj = sumj + Cells(iMax, j)
  Next
    sum = sumi + sumj
Cells(N + 5, 5) = sum
Cells(N + 5, 1) = " Сумма  эл-ов:  = "


sump = 0
For i = 1 To M
  For j = 1 To N
     If Cells(i, j) > 0 Then
      pol = Cells(i, j): jpol = j: ipol = i
      End If
      Next
Next i

For i = ipol To 1 Step -1
  For j = jpol To 1 Step -1
sump = (sump + Cells(j, i))
        Next
Next i
Cells(N + 11, 5) = sump
Cells(N + 11, 1) = " summa el do last pologitelnogo :  = "
Cells(N + 17, 5) = pol
Cells(N + 17, 1) = " pologitel el:  = "
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: Перебирай массив с конца...

Comment: *нашел ...* Ну так убери лишний код-то... а заодно откомментируй свои мысли в том, что останется.

Comment: Неправильно нашел. *Max* суммируется два раза. Надо `sum = sumi + sumj - Max`

Comment: @vikttur спасибо

Comment: @Akina теперь считает.

`For i = ipol To 1 Step -1
  For j = jpol To 1 Step -1
  sump = sump + Cells(i, j)
     Next
Next i
sump = sump - pol`

Comment: А что такое "до последнего положительного" применительно к ДВУМЕРНОМУ массиву? и в любом случае - суммировать-то надо не всё... а сначала найти этот "последний положительный", который теперь будет первый попавшийся, и только затем начинать суммировать. Кстати, а его поиск ведь можно учинить параллельно с выполнением первой, уже решённой, задачи - чего два раза бегать-то?

Comment: @Akina я же нашел последний положительный  элемент и его положение в массиве, и с этого положения делал перебор с конца или что-то не так , извините если слишком глупый

Comment: Все можно определить в одной паре вложенных циклов. После этого суммировать нужное. И у Вас путаница в коде `N` - к-во столбцов, но при выводе результата Вы `N` добавляете к строкам.

Comment: Уточните расположение поседнего положительного. Искать в строке, столбце или на правом нижнем пересечении?

Comment: @vikttur на правом нижнем пересечении

Comment: Сам запутался и Вас запутал. Нет правого нижнего пересечения. Есть или нижнее правое для строки, или нижнее правое для столбца. В коде (в ответе)  определяется крайнее правое в строке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работа с листом медленная, поэтому формирование матрицы и счет производим в массиве, к листу обращаемся только для выгрузки результата.

Определение `Max`, `Plus` и их положение в матрице происходит в одной паре циклов. Это уменьшило время выполнения кода, но немного увеличило используемую память (добавлены две переменные).

Обратный счет в циклах. Если нашли значение `Plus`, то лишнюю проверку обрезаем. Но тут момент... Может быть несколько одинаковых `Max` и в циклах с обратным отсчетом буде найдено пересечение для верхнего левого `Max`.

Для избежания ошибки суммирование по `Max` и `Plus` разнесено отдельно, т.к. теоретически возможно отсутствие положительных значений.

Суммируются значения на пересечении строки/столбца с `Max` или `Plus`:

```
Private Sub cmdb2_Click()
    Dim arrM()
    Dim lRw As Long, lClmn As Long, lMax As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lSum As Long
    Dim iRowMax As Long, jColMax As Long, iRowPlus As Long, jColPlus As Long
        Cells.Clear
        lRw = Val(txt1.Value): lClmn = Val(txt2.Value)
        If lRw <= 0 Or lClmn <= 0 Then Exit Sub

        ReDim arrM(1 To lRw, 1 To lClmn + 5)

        For i = lRw To 1 Step -1
            For j = lClmn To 1 Step -1
                arrM(i, j) = Int(-19 * Rnd + 10)

                If arrM(i, j) >= lMax Then
                    lMax = arrM(i, j): iRowMax = i: jColMax = j
                End If

                If iRowPlus = 0 Then
                    If arrM(i, j) > 0 Then iRowPlus = i: jColPlus = j
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        For i = 1 To lRw
            lSum = lSum + arrM(i, jColMax)
        Next i

        For j = 1 To lClmn
            lSum = lSum + arrM(iRowMax, j)
        Next j

        arrM(1, lClmn + 2) = "Max элемент"
        arrM(2, lClmn + 2) = lMax
        arrM(1, lClmn + 3) = "Сумма  эл-ов с Max"
        arrM(2, lClmn + 3) = lSum - lMax

        lSum = 0

        If iRowPlus > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To lRw
                lSum = lSum + arrM(i, jColPlus)
            Next i

            For j = 1 To lClmn
                lSum = lSum + arrM(iRowPlus, j)
            Next j
        End If

        arrM(1, lClmn + 4) = "Plus элемент"
        arrM(2, lClmn + 4) = arrM(iRowPlus, jColPlus)
        arrM(1, lClmn + 5) = "Сумма  эл-ов с Plus"
        arrM(2, lClmn + 5) = lSum - arrM(iRowPlus, jColPlus)

        Cells(1, 1).Resize(lRw, UBound(arrM, 2)).Value = arrM
    End Sub
```

Второй вариант - сумма на пересечении крайнего правого `Max`, сумма диапазона до крайнего правого `Plus` (включительно):

```
Private Sub cmdb2_Click()
Dim arrM()
Dim lRw As Long, lClmn As Long, lMax As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lSum As Long, a As Long, b As Long
Dim iRowMax As Long, jColMax As Long, iRowPlus As Long, jColPlus As Long
    Cells.Clear
    lRw = Val(txt1.Value) + 1: lClmn = Val(txt2.Value)
    a = Val(txt3.Value): b = Val(txt4.Value)
    If lRw <= 0 Or lClmn <= 0 Then Exit Sub
    lMax = a - 1

    ReDim arrM(1 To lRw, 1 To lClmn + 5)
    arrM(1, 1) = "Матрица " & lRw - 1 & " x " & lClmn

    For i = 2 To lRw
        For j = 1 To lClmn
            arrM(i, j) = Int((b - a + 1) * Rnd + a)

            If arrM(i, j) >= lMax Then
                lMax = arrM(i, j): iRowMax = i: jColMax = j
            End If

            If arrM(i, j) > 0 Then
                iRowPlus = i: jColPlus = j
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = 2 To lRw
        lSum = lSum + arrM(i, jColMax)
    Next i

    For j = 1 To lClmn
        lSum = lSum + arrM(iRowMax, j)
    Next j

    arrM(1, lClmn + 2) = "Max элемент"
    arrM(1, lClmn + 3) = "Сумма  эл-ов с Max"
    arrM(2, lClmn + 2) = lMax
    arrM(2, lClmn + 3) = lSum - lMax

    arrM(1, lClmn + 4) = "Plus элемент"
    arrM(1, lClmn + 5) = "Сумма  эл-ов с Plus"

    If iRowPlus > 0 Then
        lSum = 0

        For i = 2 To iRowPlus
            For j = 1 To jColPlus
                lSum = lSum + arrM(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i

        arrM(2, lClmn + 4) = arrM(iRowPlus, jColPlus)
        arrM(2, lClmn + 5) = lSum
    End If

    Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arrM), UBound(arrM, 2)).Value = arrM
End Sub
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста , почему сумма после положительного получилось 7 на скриншоте  https://ibb.co/gGq5yV

Comment: В условии - до последнего элемента, я же посчитал на пересечении... Покажите по Вашей картинке, какие значения должны суммироваться (с учетом положения `Plus` или без учета строки и столбца). Подправлю. Там еще несколько штрихов исправить.

Comment: понял как Вы считали, и немного переделал, преподаватель одобрил

Comment: Отлично. Добавил второй вариант, может, пригодится кому.

Comment: может еще подскажете идею как сделать такое задание: Сжать массив, удалив из него все элементы, модуль которых находится в интервале [a,b]. Освободившиеся в конце массива элементы заполнить нулями.

Comment: Это другой вопрос. Создавайте, спрашивайте. Но с учетом недочетов: нормальное название; пример своей работы; описание задачи; что не получается.